# looping through json data and match to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, if-statement

I am trying to match an array to an value of an object in my json, and then pull the other values in that object in a div, but it seems that it only matches to the last object of my json data.
my array is **countryPath** which will have the the value **de-de** in the page, based on my URL. I want to show the details of the objects that have **urlCode** of **de-de**

also my code is javascript, I would like to convert it to Jquery if possible?

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Germany",
  "countryCode": "DE",
  "urlCode": "de-de",
  "standardPrice": "22",
  "standardFreeOver": "0",
  "standardTimes": "x"
},
{
  "name": "United Kingdom",
  "countryCode": "GB",
  "urlCode": "en-gb",
  "standardPrice": "30",
  "standardFreeOver": "x",
  "standardTimes": "x"
}];

data.forEach((o) => {
  if (countryPath.includes(o.urlCode)) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<div class="' + o.countryCode + '"><div class="header"><h2>' + o.name + '</h2><img src="https://gepi.global-e.com/content/images/flags/' + o.imgCode + '.png"></div><h3>STANDARD DELIVERY</h3><br><p>Price: ' + o.standardPrice + ' or free for orders over ' + o.standardFreeOver +
      '<br>Delivery Time:' + o.standardTimes + ' working days</p></div>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<div><p>please choose a country</p></div>';
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to append, hence, use `+=`. `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=`

Comment: jquery is just a library written in JS, if you want to use jquery, just use it. What is countryPath? I don't entirely understand what you want and what is the problem

Comment: countryPath is an array which I already have, the value in this instance on the page I am using this function brings de-de I have explained this in my question.

Comment: I also have used append , this part : document.getElementById('output').innerHTML isnt the issues, its the looping that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.find` instead, which will return the matching object if it fulfills the condition, and populate `output` *outside* of the loop. If the object was found, populate using that object, else go with `please choose a country`, using the conditional operator to keep your code more DRY:

```
const o = data.find(o => countryPath.includes(o.urlCode));
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =
  o
  ? '<div class="' + o.countryCode + ...
  : '<div><p>please choose a country</p></div>';
```

Comment: the reason I am using if statement here is that I need two arguments, one that if the array countryPath matches the urlCode to show the other values in my html, if not ask to choose a country from a drop down list I have.

Comment: Yes, you can use `.find` instead to achieve that, to try to find a matching object, and if the matching object is not found, output `choose a country`

Comment: ok thanks can you please amend the above to write the whole code fully?

Comment: thank you so much that works never used the const before